# How to get value of select option inside for loop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, for-loop, select

I have a select option like this:

```
<select name="color" id="multipleAttr" class="form-control select-2">
   <option value="blue">
   <option value="red">
</select>
```

Now in order to return the value of this with jQuery, I did this:

```
$(".select-2").change(function() {
      var val = $(".select-2").val();
      console.log(val);
});
```

It works fine and properly shows the value of selected item.

But I wanted to make this more dynamically by using a for loop:

```
var counters = 2;

for(i=2;i<=counters;i++){
   $(".select-"+i).change(function() {
      var val = $(".select-"+i).val();
      console.log(val);
   });
}
```

So it should be selecting `select-2` class value and returns it as `val`.

But it prints **undefined** somehow.

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Does it print undefined when you're changing `.select-1` or `.select-2`?

Comment: infamous for loop. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: You realize that you don't need a loop right? JQuery binds `this` in event handlers and does all the heavy lifting for you: `$('select[class=^="select-"]').change(function() { var val = $(this).val(); console.log(val); });`.

Comment: Use a common class! Why are you binding multiple things. Use jQuery and let the library handle it! `$(".select").change(function() {
      var val = $(this).val();
      console.log(val);
   });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the event provided to you in the .change method instead of again getting the element from dom in the .change callback.

So your code will be like

```
var counters = 2;

for(i=2;i<=counters;i++){
   $(".select-"+i).change(function(event) {
      var val = event.target.value;
      console.log(val);
   });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: `element` is a bad name for `event`

Comment: `element.target.value` sort of defeats the purpose of jQuery...

Comment: @code I don't think so as jquery provides us this feature we should take benefit from this to avoid extra execution of finding element again from dom.

Comment: I meant that you could (and should) have used `$(this).val()`.

Comment: Yeah, that's also a good suggestion maybe you make an edit to answer.

Answer (score 1):

For that matter, why loop through classnames with numbers? Just set a single class to represent all select elements with the functionality, and then set data-attributes for other info if you need it.

```js
$('.select').change(function() {
  let val = $(this).val();
  let myName = $(this).data('num');
  console.log(`new val is ${val} from ${myName}`);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='select' data-num='select-1'>
  <option selected></option>
  <option value='33'>33</option>
</select>
<select class='select' data-num='select-2'>
  <option selected></option>
  <option value='55'>55</option>
</select>
```